# Как сделать, чтобы обращение к серверу было только каждые N страниц?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

Использую плагин `jquery` - datatables. Есть возможность подгрузить данные с сервера и сделать пагинацию.

Но данных может быть слишком много, чтобы выгружать их всех на клиент часть, а при наличии пагинации каждый раз обращаться к серверу, чтобы извлечь данные - не имеет смысла (теряется весь смысл использования datatables).

Вопрос: можно ли в datables сделать так, чтобы обращаться за очередной порцией данных на сервер только каждые N страниц? Например он загружает первые 10 на клиент и если человек кликает на страницы с 1 по 10 - то работает клиентская часть, как только кликнул на страницу 11 или 12 например, то отрабатывает подгрузка данных ещё на очередные 10 страниц?

P.S. Помню, что подобное вроде было, но сейчас не могу найти

Comment: Вы сами себе перечите... _каждый раз обращаться к серверу, чтобы извлечь данные - не имеет смысла (теряется весь смысл использования datatables)._ смысл serverdide как-раз в том, что пагинация загружается если открывать следующие страницы; а далее вы хотите _обращаться за очередной порцией данных на сервер_ в datatable есть параметр length и на сервер всегда летит start по которым легко прописать тот же limit, или вариант получше - выбирать записи по id

Comment: @InDevX "пагинация загружается если открывать следующие страницы" - nope. Можно этого избежать. Ответ ниже

Answer (score 1):

Кажется я нашел.

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html - Pipelining data to reduce Ajax calls for paging

Пример работы с JS:

```
//
// Pipelining function for DataTables. To be used to the `ajax` option of DataTables
//
$.fn.dataTable.pipeline = function ( opts ) {
    // Configuration options
    var conf = $.extend( {
        pages: 5,     // number of pages to cache
        url: '',      // script url
        data: null,   // function or object with parameters to send to the server
                      // matching how `ajax.data` works in DataTables
        method: 'GET' // Ajax HTTP method
    }, opts );
 
    // Private variables for storing the cache
    var cacheLower = -1;
    var cacheUpper = null;
    var cacheLastRequest = null;
    var cacheLastJson = null;
 
    return function ( request, drawCallback, settings ) {
        var ajax          = false;
        var requestStart  = request.start;
        var drawStart     = request.start;
        var requestLength = request.length;
        var requestEnd    = requestStart + requestLength;
         
        if ( settings.clearCache ) {
            // API requested that the cache be cleared
            ajax = true;
            settings.clearCache = false;
        }
        else if ( cacheLower < 0 || requestStart < cacheLower || requestEnd > cacheUpper ) {
            // outside cached data - need to make a request
            ajax = true;
        }
        else if ( JSON.stringify( request.order )   !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.order ) ||
                  JSON.stringify( request.columns ) !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.columns ) ||
                  JSON.stringify( request.search )  !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.search )
        ) {
            // properties changed (ordering, columns, searching)
            ajax = true;
        }
         
        // Store the request for checking next time around
        cacheLastRequest = $.extend( true, {}, request );
 
        if ( ajax ) {
            // Need data from the server
            if ( requestStart < cacheLower ) {
                requestStart = requestStart - (requestLength*(conf.pages-1));
 
                if ( requestStart < 0 ) {
                    requestStart = 0;
                }
            }
             
            cacheLower = requestStart;
            cacheUpper = requestStart + (requestLength * conf.pages);
 
            request.start = requestStart;
            request.length = requestLength*conf.pages;
 
            // Provide the same `data` options as DataTables.
            if ( typeof conf.data === 'function' ) {
                // As a function it is executed with the data object as an arg
                // for manipulation. If an object is returned, it is used as the
                // data object to submit
                var d = conf.data( request );
                if ( d ) {
                    $.extend( request, d );
                }
            }
            else if ( $.isPlainObject( conf.data ) ) {
                // As an object, the data given extends the default
                $.extend( request, conf.data );
            }
 
            return $.ajax( {
                "type":     conf.method,
                "url":      conf.url,
                "data":     request,
                "dataType": "json",
                "cache":    false,
                "success":  function ( json ) {
                    cacheLastJson = $.extend(true, {}, json);
 
                    if ( cacheLower != drawStart ) {
                        json.data.splice( 0, drawStart-cacheLower );
                    }
                    if ( requestLength >= -1 ) {
                        json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );
                    }
                     
                    drawCallback( json );
                }
            } );
        }
        else {
            json = $.extend( true, {}, cacheLastJson );
            json.draw = request.draw; // Update the echo for each response
            json.data.splice( 0, requestStart-cacheLower );
            json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );
 
            drawCallback(json);
        }
    }
};
 
// Register an API method that will empty the pipelined data, forcing an Ajax
// fetch on the next draw (i.e. `table.clearPipeline().draw()`)
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'clearPipeline()', function () {
    return this.iterator( 'table', function ( settings ) {
        settings.clearCache = true;
    } );
} );
 
 
//
// DataTables initialisation
//
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
            url: 'scripts/server_processing.php',
            pages: 5 // number of pages to cache
        } )
    } );
} );
```

html:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```